# MySQL - Are memory table queries slowing down other queries

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I'm planning to limit "main tables" (innodb) queries from requests by putting some limitation by ip per minute. My idea is to create mysql table which contains ip, datetime and request type. The problem is when somebody will try brute force and limiting table will block his actions. Will massive ammount of queries to memory table kill the rest of the queries in innodb tables?

If yes, how can I maximize the capacity of main database having the possibility to limit request of certain type from certain ip certain times per minute?

Comment: "per minute" seems slow to me. MySQL is capable of faster throughput.  What makes you think this design is necessary?  I'll bet your idea of "massive" isn't a problem for a properly designed and indexed schema.

Comment: @duffymo I want to limit some actions in order to prevent brute forcing login (10 tries per minute), spamming register (1 time per hour), or requesting some data too often with some complex queries (everything by ip).

Comment: That should not be done by the database; your middle tier needs to enforce it.  I still say that you're underestimating the database and the query optimizer.  I would not take such a step until measured responses told me it was necessary.

Comment: @duffymo You've got some right, but still I need to prevent bruteforcing login or spamming register. Even ignoring the performance, it's security issue.

Comment: No, it's not.  Count the number of retries on the middle tier and deny access when you hit the limit.  That's entirely different from the overly complex solution you've proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will massive ammount of queries to memory table kill the rest of the
>   queries in innodb tables?

- No! It will not kill the queries for sure. But you should keep in mind few things.
- Memory table will grow as new data come in and it will grab the space in system RAM.
- This will not harm your innodb as bufferpool is allocated as mysql starts
- This will be harful if system reaches to max memory due to growth of your memory table (consumed all ram)! and then you're going to see mysql getting killed by kernel mentioning "out of memory" error.

> If yes, how can I maximize the capacity of main database having the
>   possibility to limit request of certain type from certain ip per
>   minute?

- As such the answer is NO but still you can create your user with restricted use of resources.
- Review [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html) to create user with such limitations.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much. Consider adding some information how can I limit the size of table and remove old rows by some key to make place for a new ones. Should I use triggers before Insert?